# .Net multiline regex with a hex address

Tags: .net, regex, multiline

I'm very close but can't close the deal on this multi-line regex capture. I want to capture just a hex address, but only when the hex address is followed by "wtf" on the next line.

Here's a sample of the log:

```
1616846098450
trying : 16633299966633299966633299
0x4d68c66a4b7ac51f87e22d0e0b70a4ebc7f6286e7834ec3da18c6147f578afe8
wtf
0x848fcea771facf657677f1f3a919ab7e43b1f7d0df95bf8375113c5621e063c2
```

Here's the regex I'm using:

```
0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+\nwtf
```

It incorrectly captures the wtf as well. I am using this in a windows app that uses the .Net regex engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a positive look-ahead assertion to the "wtf" part. This way, it will be matched but not captured (I'm including the new line in the look-behind here as I assume it will get stripped anyway). Demo is [here](https://regex101.com/r/GtGofR/1).

```regex
0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+(?=\nwtf)
```

Comment: Thank you @Heinzi for pointing out my mistake. I thought one thing and wrote the other. I've edited my answer.

Comment: It turns out that the app (WinAutomation) strips new lines from the text, but this answer got me info I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can put a capturing group around the hex you want to capture (I'm guessing you don't want `0x`? And then you can ignore the `\nwtf` part:

- [`0[xX]([0-9a-fA-F]+)\nwtf`](https://regex101.com/r/JiOfSO/2)

[image]